# Modify the JSON output with Mule and Jersey

Tags: json, rest, jersey, mule

My goal is stupidly simple. 
I just want to wrap a json response from Jersey module in Mule in a JSON response such that:

```
{"status": "ok", message:<json-message>}
```

I tried to use a custom-transformer:

```
<flow name="sicsRest" doc:name="sicsRest">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:65432/RestServices" 
        exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="RestEntry" />
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="serviceImpl" />
        </component>
        <custom-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String" 
            class="com.hyperborea.sicsbus.transformer.JsonTransformer" 
            doc:name="JsonTransformer" />
        <jersey:exception-mapper 
            class="com.hyperborea.sicsbus.exception.JsonRestExceptionMapper" />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

The transformer class:

```
public class JsonTransformer extends AbstractTransformer {
    @Override 
    protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) 
    throws TransformerException {
        return "{\"status\":\"ok\", \"message\":\"" + src + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it raises an exception during Mule startup:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'custom-transformer'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-component, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey":exception-mapper}' is expected.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you place your `custom-transformer` in a `<response> ... </response>` block between the `inbound-endpoint` and the `jersey:resources`?

### EDIT

New flow:

```
<flow name="sicsRest" doc:name="sicsRest">
    <inbound-endpoint ... />
    <response>
        <custom-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String"
            class="com.hyperborea.sicsbus.transformer.JsonTransformer"
            doc:name="JsonTransformer" />
    </response>
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
        <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="serviceImpl" />
        </component>
        <jersey:exception-mapper ... />
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

The transformer has to be changed in an AbstractMessageTransformer in order to better handle the input (which is almost impossibile with AbstractTransformer):

```
public class JsonTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {
    @Override 
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
    throws TransformerException {
        try {
            return "{\"status\":\"ok\", \"message.getPayloadAsString()\":\"" 
            + src + "\"}";
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: The result of `src.toString` is `org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter$1@58caf6e7`. Unfortunately the instance is not castable to MuleResponseWriter because of the `$1` suffix. I found a reference to that object in [Jersey Module Reference page](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Jersey+Module+Reference#JerseyModuleReference-SendingJerseyresponsetootherflows) but I cannot understand how to apply it to my case, because it is not clear what the `message` variable is.

Comment: The payload is an instance of `org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler`. The particular implementation happens to be in `org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter`, hence the `$1`. So you can cast the payload to `org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler` but not `org.mule.module.jersey.MuleResponseWriter`.